# Mixed-model specification in R - exploring individual differences

Tags: r, lme4-nlme, mixed-model

My current experiment aims to explore the effect of viewing condition, difficulty and depth perception on object grasping. I'm mostly interested in the effect of individual differences in depth perception.

I've previously been specifying my model as a mixed-factor ANOVA, with viewing condition (binocular, monocular) and difficulty (5 levels) as repeated-measures factors and ability to perceive depth as a between subjects factor (raw data for this was logarithmic, I separated the participants into two groups ['Good' vs 'Poor'] depending on which side of a threshold their scores fell on).

Since I'm interested in individual differences, the idea of using mixed-models is appealing, but I can't quite grasp how to explore the effect of depth perception using this technique.

I understand that viewing condition and difficulty would be fixed factors. I think that both ID and depth perception would be random effects, so I can specify the model like so:

`fit.1 <- lme(Accuracy ~ Difficulty*View, random=~1|ID/DepthPerception, data=mydata)`

Am I correct in thinking that I can leave the depth perception data in its logarithmic form? Having fit this model, I cannot figure out how to interpret the effect of depth perception - only the fixed effects show up in the results.

Comment: Depth perception is a fixed effect, not a random effect. You'd specify something like `lme(Accuracy ~ Difficulty*View*DepthPerception, random=~1|ID)`, depending on which fixed effects you want to include. If you're interested in individual differences, then you'd be looking at the variance of the intercepts once you get the output.

Comment: Sorry, what I'd understood from reading things online was that anything not directly under your control was a random effect.

Are you able to give any example of how I could use the variance of the intercepts to tell me about individual differences?

Comment: If there are individual differences, then variance in intercepts will be > 0. Random effects are clustering units, i.e. units that (presumably) create some dependency in the data; in this case, you have repeated measures, and you expect measures from a given individual to be more similar between themselves than across individuals. Examples are observations nested within individuals (as here), students nested within classrooms, plants nested in geographical area (if you're in ecology), etc... The fixed effects are exactly the same as in ANOVA or regression.

Comment: Regarding that fixed effects are the same as in an ANOVA - the output I get from `summary(model1)`is confusing. Previous ANOVA said there was a main effect of `View`, but the mixed-effects model only gives me `view1` and `view2` and neither are significant.

Comment: You interpret the coefficients as you would in regression, not ANOVA. (i.e. view1 and view2 are dummy-coded variables.) If you're not familiar with the interpretation of regression coefficients, you would need to look into that first.